# Windows 10 - exe always running as administrator - how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, compatibility, uac

I have just installed a software package on my Windows 10 system - admittedly an old one designed for Windows 95, but I guess that's an aside.

It seems to have installed OK, and it seems to run OK, but for one issue.  One of the EXEs for some strange reason will only run as administrator.  In Properties → Compatibility → Settings, 'Run this program as an administrator' is unticked.  Nonetheless, the icon has the shield overlay, and I get the annoying User Account Control prompt when I run it.

Nothing relating to running as admin is appearing in Properties → General → Advanced.

I've seen suggestions that giving everyone 'Full control' access in Properties → Security would do the trick, but it is having no effect as I try.  Besides, none of the other EXEs have this set, so this can't be the cause.

I have also tried rebooting my system, and this had no effect either.

What could be causing this?  How can I fix?

Comment: What's the name of the executable?

Comment: Being it’s an old program, it probably does need admin access to work. They didn’t design applications according to today’s standards back then. This is not uncommon at all. It’s one of those things you need to live with if you’re going to run a 23 year old program. However you can try the application compatibility toolkit to tell Windows not to elevate the app. https://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/08/get-rid-of-uac-prompts-with-microsofts-application-compatibility-toolkit/

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Play.exe
Why?

Comment: @Stewart Windows will automatically run some programs elevated based on certain criteria. One is the filename. However play is not one of them.